# Vaex column doesn't evaluate

Tags: vaex

I have the following calculation:

```
df.t =100.0*((1.25/1023)*df.t-0.5)
```

Strangely, `>>>df` doesn't show result, only old values in that column. However, `df.t` shows calculated values.

So, when I export result to pandas `with dfp = df.to_pandas_df()`, it gets raw old values as well. And even `dfp.t = df.t` doesn't help.

So, how do I get calculated values?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the vaex docs I found that `df.materialize('t', inplace=True)` should likely help, but it didn't.

Finally, I tried

```
df['t'] =100.0*((1.25/1023)*df.t-0.5)
```

and that worked. I'm not sure why, since I thought `df.t` and `df['t']` to be synonyms.

But anyways, problem is solved.